# React Query with TypeScript - how to force the rule that the query key always needs to be an array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I am new in TypeScript and we want to somehow "extend" the existing useQuery hook from react-query by the rule that *the query key needs to be an array keys with 2 items at least*. Something like

```
const { data } = useQuery<Data, Error>(["module_1", "fetchA"], fetchFn); // OK
const { data } = useQuery<Data, Error>("module_1", fetchFn); // there should be TS error because queryKey is not array
const { data } = useQuery<Data, Error>(["module_1"], fetchFn); // there should be TS error because array has only 1 item
```

1. how to "extend" the useQuery hook
2. how to add such a type in TS

Thank you in advance

Comment: it worth creating a simple wrapper, for instance `useQuery2` which will call `useQuery` under the hood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a more strict `Data` type like such:

```
type Data = [any, any, ...any[]];
```

This is a tuple telling the compiler `Data` should *at least* contain 2 elements and can contain "an infinity" more

Replace the `any`'s with the actual type you need to use. This will result in errors when trying to use something else than an array of length < 2

```
const a: Data = [1];
// will raise a compiler error:
// Type '[number]' is not assignable to type '[any, any, ...any[]]'.
//  Source has 1 element(s) but target requires 2.
```

From what I gathered here https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys queries base type is `string | unknown[]` so you can try to follow this typing closely with something like this:

```
type QueryTuple = [unknown, unknown, ...unknown[]];
// ...
const { data } = useQuery<QueryTuple, Error>(["module_1", "fetchA"], fetchFn);
```

or in your case, simply restrict it to the `string` type:

```
type QueryTuple = [string, string, ...string[]];
// ...
const { data } = useQuery<QueryTuple, Error>(["module_1", "fetchA"], fetchFn);
```

Comment: This is my first time hearing about Tuple type. Thank you for detailed explanation!!